# Trouble creating an SFML Window

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, sfml

When trying to create an SFML window, `sf::VideoMode(800, 600)` gives a constructor not viable error.

Source code:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Pong");

    return 0;
}
```

Error log:

```
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target pong-cpp
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pong-cpp.dir/src/main.cpp.o
/Users/larrymason/Desktop/repos/pong-cpp/src/main.cpp:4:23: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'sf::VideoMode'
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Pong");
                      ^             ~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/SFML/Window/VideoMode.hpp:61:14: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const sf::Vector2u' (aka 'const Vector2<unsigned int>') for 1st argument
    explicit VideoMode(const Vector2u& modeSize, unsigned int modeBitsPerPixel = 32);
             ^
/usr/local/include/SFML/Window/VideoMode.hpp:42:23: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
class SFML_WINDOW_API VideoMode
                      ^
/usr/local/include/SFML/Window/VideoMode.hpp:42:23: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
/usr/local/include/SFML/Window/VideoMode.hpp:52:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
    VideoMode();
    ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pong-cpp.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pong-cpp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

To my understanding and from the tutorials I've read/watched, this is the standard way of creating a window.  I can successfully create the window using a `sf::Vector2<unsigned int>` however from looking at the SFML tutorials, this doesn't appear to be necessary.

Is this just the new way? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Strange error. Maybe try a few different ways, e.g. `sf::VideoMode{800, 600}` or just create the `VideoMode` object on the stack (i.e. declare it first) and then pass it to the constructor of `Window`. Also take a look at their [docs](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1VideoMode.php#a9478572db06121f70260e6b9dc21704e).

Comment: https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/include/SFML/Window/VideoMode.hpp
Latest file on Github only shows a ctor taking a vector2 maybe the docs are old? Which version are you using? The [change](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/commit/0785093ebc50de5df30043082611cb2430584cf0) seems to be 2 weeks old.

Comment: As digito_evo said, this is the new way, guess they forgot to update the docs/didn't have time, maybe that'll be a task for me!

Comment: @larrymason01 i posted my comment first, so its as i said ;) (11 min prior to their answer)

Comment: @Borgleader I completely read that wrong! Credit to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this just the new way?

Yes, they have made some changes.

Here are the changes from the source file:
This:

```
VideoMode(unsigned int modeWidth, unsigned int modeHeight, unsigned int modeBitsPerPixel = 32);
```

is now this:

```
explicit VideoMode(const Vector2u& modeSize, unsigned int modeBitsPerPixel = 32);
```

Take a look at it [here](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/commit/0785093ebc50de5df30043082611cb2430584cf0#diff-844b4b63f212245e606c8b919284ece33c3bd78e978769a8fd1001820cf2040bR61).

Comment: I assumed this was the case, I did `sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(sf::Vector2u(800, 600)), "Pong");` and this solved the issue, thanks for confirming!

Comment: @larrymason01 The commit is from 13 days ago so it's still a fresh change. They probably don't have the time to update their docs yet. And then it leads to confusion. You can check the related header files on their repo whenever such an error appears. After all this is one of the upsides of open-source software.